# codeigniter: how to check radio buttons depending upon the value retrieve from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a form having two radio buttons.

When i click the edit link from my html table then the radio button value should check depending on the value value received from db.

I tried the following code. But i am not getting radio button checked according to the value. it always checked the first radio button.

Please help me to solve this issue.

view page

```
<label for="level1" ><input type="radio" id="level1" name="menu_type" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('fmenu_type', '1', TRUE); ?> />Do't have sub menu</label>
<label for="level2"  ><input type="radio" id="level2" name="menu_type" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('fmenu_type', '2'); ?> />Having Sub Menu</label>
<?php echo form_submit($submitbtn);
```

controller

```
 if((int)$mainmenu_id > 0)//this is for edit ,when value id is greater then 0
  {    
       $query = $this->mainmenumodel->get($mainmenu_id);
       $data['fmainmenu_id']['value'] = $query['mainmenu_id'];
       $data['fmenu_name']['value'] = $query['menu_name']; 
       $data['menu_type']  ['value'] = $query['menu_type']; //i am trying to set through this
       $data["query"] = $this->mainmenumodel->fetch_mainmenu_data($config["per_page"], $page);
       $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['fmenu_type']['value'] = $query['menu_type']; 

         $this->load->view('admin/setups/mainmenu/index',$data);  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the third parameter according to the content of the `$data` variable.

So you will have something similar:

```
<label for="level1" ><input type="radio" id="level1" name="menu_type" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('fmenu_type', '1', $menu_type['value'] == '1'); ?> />Do't have sub menu</label>
<label for="level2"  ><input type="radio" id="level2" name="menu_type" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('fmenu_type', '2', $menu_type['value'] == '2'); ?> />Having Sub Menu</label>
<?php echo form_submit($submitbtn);
```

You can check the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) here and you'll see that the third argument specifies which one of the radio buttons to select, you just need to specify the right condition based on your data.

**EDIT:** I updated the code, so that most probably it works as you expect. The idea is as follows: the `set_radio` function can take 3 arguments `(name, value, is_checked)` if `is_checked` is true, then the radio button will be selected, otherwise it will not be. For example, this code will always put a radio button which is checked by default:

```
<label for="level1" ><input type="radio" id="level1" name="menu_type" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('fmenu_type', '1', TRUE); ?> />Do't have sub menu</label>
```

Now because you don't want it to always be selected you have to specify a condition which will either be `true` or `false` so that it will either select it or not. This is why I compared the value of `$menu_type['value']` to `'1'`. Since you this code is in the view, and you are passing this from the controller, the way you access the data passed is by using the keys of the `$data` array you passed, in this case: `menu_type`, `links`, `query`, etc...

Comment: Getting error 4 errors:  `Illegal string offset 'value'  in  controllers/mainmenusetups.php`   2. `Message: Illegal string offset 'value' Filename: controllers/mainmenusetups.php`  3. `Message: Undefined variable: data Filename: mainmenu/index.php`      `Message: Undefined variable: data Filename: mainmenu/index.php`

Comment: It all depends on your data, and what there is in it. It seems from your code that you need `$menu_type['value'] == XXX` instead of `$data['...']`. Again, you know how and based on what you want to select one radio button or the other, so use your data accordingly.

Comment: what you are trying to explain, i am not understanding!!   my radio button should checked on depending upon two value `1` or `2`  if from controller i am getting value for `menu_type` is 1 then my first radio button should be checked Otherwise if value for `menu_type`  is `2` then my second radio button should checked. From my controlller i am getting  value `2` for a row using `$data['menu_type']  ['value'] = $query['menu_type'];`  SO how can i checked the second radio becoz its value is 2.